# Does Sahih al-Bukhari 5590 contradict Bukhari 3931?

Tags: hadith, contradiction

> Narrated Abu 'Amir or Abu Malik Al-Ash'ari:
>
> that he heard the Prophet (ﷺ) saying, "From among my followers there will be some people who will consider illegal sexual intercourse, the wearing of silk, the drinking of alcoholic drinks and the use of **musical instruments, as lawful**. And there will be some people who will stay near the side of a mountain and in the evening their shepherd will come to them with their sheep and ask them for something, but they will say to him, 'Return to us tomorrow.' Allah will destroy them during the night and will let the mountain fall on them, and He will transform the rest of them into monkeys and pigs and they will remain so till the Day of Resurrection.

This hadith controdicts this one :

> That once Abu Bakr came to her on the day of Id-ul-Fitr or Id ul Adha while the Prophet (ﷺ) was with her and there were two girl singers with her, singing songs of the Ansar about the day of Buath. Abu Bakr said twice. "Musical instrument of Satan!" But the Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Leave them Abu Bakr, for every nation has an Id (i.e. festival) and this day is our Id."
>
> [Source](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3931)

In one hadith prophet Muhammad(PBUH) is saying, "*Leave them Abu Bakr, for every nation has an Id (i.e. festival) and this day is our Id."*, means that he had no problem with music. But in the first hadith he is saying that music is illegal.

Comment: The hadith doesn't say that the prophet had no problem with music. From where do you conclude a general rule, when the statement already includes something that could be regarded a restriction "this day is Id" further it describes the music of instruments used (2nd restriction).

Comment: @Medi1Saif ohhh OK, but can you answer it

Comment: @Medi1Saif If its okay to use (satanic according to abu bakr) musical instruments on Id, then is it okay to wear silk, drink alcohol, have illegal sexual intercourse on Id too?

Comment: @Hisham so is abu Bakr the Messenger of Allah or our prophet? Whom gets revelation and taught Muslims what is halal and what is haram and when? Abu Bakr acted or judged upon his interpretation while Muhammad told him it is permissible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can sum up without conflict; musical instruments and music is unlawful with minor exception for Daff and that also only for few situations as pointed in Hadees.

Answer (score 0):

The point is here is that, those things being unlawful still people think it's lawful. It stressing on the fact that people would become so misinformed and would start considering things as lawful whereas they are strictly prohibited as per hadith and quran.

Wearing silk would invite fire of hell
Alcoholic drinks are never lawful in Islam and praying while intoxicated is totally bad and would give direct entry into hell

Sexual intercourse be it adultery or fornication would invite getting 100 lashes on both and their faces would be blackened on the day of judgement and Allah would never look at them also nor will purify them.
Musical instruments are discouraged in Islam since the era of Nuh PBUH as these are all things which hinder you from remembrance of Allah and doing these things would help you to be misguided in this world and the hereafter.

Considering the second hadith it may be a Hamd or praise lines in the name of Allah or they may be of totally other religions too may be as there is little information but Quran exceptionally has provided to not pursue these things.